# Unit Test - Passive View in Winforms/C#

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, c#-2.0

I've designed a Winforms App where the View has no link to the Model. It only knows about the Controller. Controller creates the view and maintains all the state and updates the view accordingly. How do I write Unit Tests for Controller class (view gets created in the constructor of the Controller class).

Comment: BTW, a Passive View normally shouldn't know about the Controller. It should just fire events for whomever will observe them.

Comment: W.r.t. your subsequent query.. yes. Composing the different classes should be done externally. The controller should have its dependencies passed into it `ControllerCtor(Model, IView)`. Creating the various objects and wiring them together should be a different responsibility and handled separately (mostly done in the Main method or declaratively via attributes/xml for a DI Framework)

Answer (score 2):

- Extract an interface for the View - say IView.
- Next instead of creating a concrete view implicitly in Controller.ctor, have it explicitly passed in (as a ctor argument which is then stored in a _view field). The type of the ctor parameter should be of type IView.

Now in your tests, you can pass in a fake view (or a mock) and verify that the right methods are called on the view.
In your production code, pass in the real view object.